# Java switch statment, search of array

Tags: java

```
//TestEmployeesProgram driver with menu & object array.
import java.util.*;
public class TestEmployeesProgram {

public static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {

    final int MAX = 7;

    Employee employee[] = new Employee[MAX];

    int choice,k;
    String name;
    boolean notFound;

    employee[0] = new Manager("Jerry Bloggs","gfr",5,38.5);
    employee[1] = new Manager("Joe Bloggs","gdr",4,32.5);
    employee[2] = new Admin("Mary Jennings","nnv",35.3,88.5,34.3);
    employee[3] = new Clerk("Brian Jones","bbl",42.4,78.5,23.5,45.3);
    employee[4] = new Manager("John Bloggs","gvr",5,33.5);
    employee[5] = new Admin("Bridget Jennings","nvv",45.3,98.5,36.3);
    employee[6] = new Clerk("Jack Jones","bbb",43.4,78.5,23.5,47.3);

    //Initial Read
    choice = showMenu();

    //Continue Until 4/Exit
    while (choice != MAX) {

        switch (choice) {
        case 1://Manager

            System.out.println();
            System.out.printf("%s %-16s %-10s %6s","Name","Id","Hours Worked","Pay");
            System.out.println("\n==================================================");

            for (k = 0; k < MAX; ++k)
            {
                if (employee[k] instanceof Manager){ //use of string method instance of.


                    System.out.println(employee[k].toString());
                }
            }
            break;

        case 2://Administration

            System.out.println();
            System.out.printf("%s %-16s %-10s %6s %-19s","Name","Id","Hours Worked","Pay","Admin Quota");
            System.out.println("\n==================================================");

            for (k = 0; k < MAX; ++k)
            {
                if (employee[k] instanceof Admin){
                System.out.println(employee[k].toString());

                }
            }
            break;

        case 3://Clerk

            System.out.println();
            System.out.printf("%s %-16s %-10s %6s %-19s","Name","Id","Hours Worked","Pay","Admin Quota","Units Sold");
            System.out.println("\n==================================================");

            for (k = 0; k < MAX; ++k)
            {
                if (employee[k] instanceof Clerk){
                System.out.println(employee[k].toString());
                }
            }
            break;
```

I was running the program and the name search in case 4 goes directly to default "employee name not found" and doesnt allow user input.I looked through the code but cant find the error,any tips or help?

```
        case 4://Name search

            System.out.print("Enter employee name: ");
            name = console.nextLine();

            k = -1;
            notFound = true;



            while ((k < MAX-1) && (notFound))
            {
                ++k;
                if (name == employee[k].getName()){

                    System.out.println();
                    System.out.printf("%s %-16s %-10s %6s %-19s","Name","Id","Hours Worked","Pay","Admin Quota","Units Sold");
                    System.out.println("\n==================================================");

                    System.out.println(employee[k].toString());
                    System.out.println();
                    notFound = false;
                }


            }//end of case 4 while.
             if (notFound){
                System.out.println("Employee name not found\n");
            }
            break;

        case 7://exit
            System.out.println("Program exiting...");
            System.exit(0);

        default:
            System.out.println("Invalid menu choice 1..3 of 7 to Exit");



        }//end of switch

        //sub read 
        choice = showMenu();

    }//end of while 






}//end of main

//Menu method for employee selection.
public static int showMenu()
{

    int choice;
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("Employee Program Menu");

    System.out.println("1.Show Manager pay details ");
    System.out.println("2.Show Admin pay details ");
    System.out.println("3.Show Clerk pay details ");
    System.out.println("4.Search by employee name ");
    System.out.println("7.Exit");


    System.out.print("Enter option: ");
    choice = console.nextInt();


    return choice;
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two errors. The first is here:

```
System.out.print("Enter option: ");
choice = console.nextInt();
```

The `nextInt` method doesn't consume the end-of-line character. Try this instead:

```
System.out.print("Enter option: ");
String line = console.nextLine();
choice = Integer.parseInt(line);
```

The second error is that here you should use `equals` instead of `==` to compare strings:

```
 if (name == employee[k].getName())
```

Try this instead:

```
 if (name.equals(employee[k].getName()))
```

The `==` operator tests to see if the two strings are the same object (i.e. the strings are at the same location in memory).

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't answer the question but this is one of the issues in his code.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (name == employee[k].getName())
```

change this to

```
if (name.equals(employee[k].getName()))
```

Comment: Doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common issue. When you use nextInt() to read an integer value only the integer character is read and the \n is left in the buffer and when you call nextLine() after that, it doesn't prompt for user entry because it already got a '\n'

To avoid this, in the showMenu method do

```
 console.nextLine();
```

after you get the choice using nextInt().

This last part of showMenu would be:

```
 choice=console.nextInt();
 console.nextLine();
 return choice;
```

and you should use .equals() method to compare strings as below.

```
 if (name.equals(employee[k].getName()))
```

Good luck :)

Comment: Youre Welcome :) Haha This qn is a typical eg where the credit didnt go to the right person! anyway.. glad we could help :)